# Delete permissions not working with Domain Access instaled

Tags: users

I have a site with [Domain Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain) module installed. I have created an Admin View, which lists types of content (exposed filter). My surprise is that a role, which is Editor (a kind of Authenticated user), and which in permissions has only Edit permissions for that kind of content, is able to Delete the node, when he/she would not be allowed according to the permissions. I have rebuilt permissions, and there appears the Delete link, and it also performs the deletion. How can I check it, maybe at low level database?

Answer (score 0):

For some unknown reasons, I had this option checked under Permissions: `Delete any content on assigned domains`. Obviously, it overrided every other permission filtered by content type. Unchecking it, the "Delete" link only appeared on the Admin role, which is what I wanted.